# Suppose $B = M_{V,V}(L_A)$, where $L_A$ is a linear transformation. Show $B$ is similar to $[[\lambda, 0]^T,[1,\lambda]^T]]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in Mat_{2,2}(\mathbb C)$ and $L_A: \mathbb C^2 \rightarrow \mathbb C^2$ given by $L_A(v) = Av$.

I've shown $A$ has at least one eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Write $V = \{v,u\}$ an ordered basis for $\mathbb C^2$, where $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.

I've shown that the matrixrepresentation of $L_A$ with respect to the ordered basis $V$ is $B = M_{V,V}(L_A) = [[\lambda, 0]^T,[\beta,\alpha]^T]$ for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$.

Now suppose $\alpha =\lambda, \beta \neq 0$, thus $B = M_{V,V}(L_A) = [[\lambda, 0]^T,[\beta,\lambda]^T]$.

How can I show $B$ is similar to $[[\lambda, 0]^T,[1,\lambda]^T]]$ ? A hint is given I could consider the matrixrepresentation of $L_A$ with respect to the ordered basis $U=[v,v+\beta^{-1}u]$, but I've not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $Av = \lambda v$. What we want is to find a vector $w$ with $Aw = v + \lambda w$. Then with respect to the basis $[v,w]$, $A$ would have the desired form. We know that $Au = \beta v + \lambda u$, by reading the second column of the matrix for $A$.

Let's use the hint: $U = [v,v + \beta^{-1}u]$, ie $w = v + \beta^{-1}u$.

Then:

\begin{align*} Aw &= A(v + \beta^{-1}u) \\ 
&= Av + \beta^{-1}Au \\
&= \lambda v + \beta^{-1}(\beta v + \lambda u) \\
&= \lambda v + v + \beta^{-1}\lambda u \\
& = v + \lambda(v + \beta^{-1} u) \\
& = v + \lambda w\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you @AlexZorn. Just to be sure: we conclude the matrices are then similar, since there exist two basis' $V,U$ such that both matrices equal one of $M_{V,V}(L), M_{U,U}(L)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is sufficient to find an invertible matrix 
$P_{2,2}$ such that 
$$BP=P\left[\begin{array}{cc} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{array}\right]. $$
In my opinion, we can just expand the equation and easily get that $P$ has the form of $$\left[\begin{array} {cc} \beta d & b \\ 0 & d \end{array}\right]$$ where $d$ is non-zero.

Comment: Others may correct me, but this seems more appropriate for a comment.